# converting input string to dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have an input string with nested keys and values. I need to convert it into a dictionary that can then be read for further processing.

The input string is as given below:

```
{'None': 'No', 'Some': 'Yes', 'Full': 'Reservation', {'Yes': 'No', 'No': 'WaitEstimate', {'0-10': 'No', '30-60': 'Type', {'Thai': 'No', 'French': 'No', 'Italian': 'Yes', 'Burger': 'Yes'}, '10-30': 'Yes', '>60': 'No'}}}
```

It needs to convert to:

```
None: No
Some: Yes
Full: Reservation {
    Yes: No
    No : WaitEstimate {
              0-10: No ........ and so on
```

Comment: great so whats the question? what are you stuck with? which part of your code isnt working?

Comment: I am unable to understand how to split it. I cant seem to understand where to start from

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a JSON. If it is, you can use the JSON library. From the [W3Schools Python JSON page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp): *"If you have a JSON string, you can parse it by using the `json.loads()` method. The result will be a Python dictionary."*

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

Comment: Please don't like to W3Schools, link to the official python docs instead, those are kept up to date.

Comment: Yes, fuller documentation might be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html. I was just attributing the direct quote, which seems to exactly answer the question ;)